# Convert cent value in integer to currency in HTML with thymleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How to display a cent value in integer as currency in thymleaf?

I am working on integration a bank API and the API is returning all the amounts in cents. I am using thymleaf as my templating engine and not able to display the amount correctly in the frontend.

For example:

The value from server = 16417
Expected output = 164.17

I tried the following expressions but I was not able to get the expected output.

1)

`<span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(page.amount, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}"></span>`

output : `16,417.00`

2)

`<span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(page.amount/100, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}"></span>`

output : `164.00`

3)

`<span th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(page.amount)}"></span>`

output: `$16,417.00`

4)

`<span th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(page.amount/100)}"></span>`

output : `$164.00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but, as is, Java is performing integer division and just dropping the fractional/decimal portion. Try forcing the program to perform "regular" division:

```
<span th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(page.amount/100.00)}"></span>
```

OR

```
<span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(page.amount/100.00, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}"></span>
```